# Integrating an array using scipy.integrate.quad and nquad "Does not return valid float"

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, quad

I want to plot a function that takes a number, uses it as a parameter in an integration, and returns the result of the integration. *The function returns values just fine when I input a single float number.* But when I give it something like numpy.linspace(0,3,500), the "quad" module in my function responds badly.

I've looked up advice to use "nquad" instead simply because it's better on arrays. Additionally, I've read the documentation and looked up the error, but none of the examples/solutions seem to involve my particular situation.

Here are my functions, and the errors that follow when I run them.

quad: "Supplied function does not return a valid float"

```
def fsum(x, dVdm, v_c, dposdmirror, gauss_width):
    integrand = lambda chi: sum_rough(x, dVdm, v_c, dposdmirror) * np.exp(-(x-chi)**2 / (2 * gauss_width))
    def_integral, err = nquad(integrand, 1, 2)
    sum_fit = def_integral * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * gauss_width ** 3) ** (-1)
    return sum_fit
```

nquad: Same error as "quad".
Here's the entire, self-sustaining code this time. I included a use of the function with a single float number.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import nquad

abs_field = .03
resistor = 9.95
avg_current = 0.08
muMs = .64
active_thick = 10e-9
mag_thick = 10e-9
width = 50E-6
t = (active_thick + mag_thick)/2
mu_0 = 1.256e-6
gyr = 1.76e11
hbar = 1.05457e-34
fund_charge = 1.602e-19

def sum_rough(x, dVdm, v_c, dposdmirror):
    sum_fit1 = (-dVdm/(muMs + abs_field)) * avg_current*mu_0 / (2 * np.pi * width)
    sum_fit2 = (np.log(t**2 + .25*(width + 2*dposdmirror*(x-v_c))**2)-np.log(t**2 + .25*(width-2*dposdmirror*(x-v_c))**2))
    sum_fit3 = sum_fit1 * sum_fit2
    sum_fit4 = sum_fit3 * np.piecewise(x, [abs(x-v_c)*dposdmirror < width/2, abs(x-v_c)*dposdmirror >= width/2], [1, 0])
    return sum_fit4

def fsum(x, dVdm, v_c, dposdmirror, gauss_width):
    integrand = lambda chi: sum_rough(x, dVdm, v_c, dposdmirror) * np.exp(-(x-chi)**2 / (2 * gauss_width))
    def_integral, err = nquad(integrand, [[1, 2]], args=None, opts=None)
    sum_fit = def_integral * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * gauss_width ** 3) ** (-1)
    return sum_fit

dVdm = -3
v_c = 1.3
dposdmirror = 30e-6
gauss_width = 50

print fsum(1.5, dVdm, v_c, dposdmirror, gauss_width)

xlin = np.linspace(0,3,500)
ything = fsum(xlin, -3, 1.3, 30e-6, 50)
plt.plot(xlin, ything)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I should mention that I need to be able to use arrays so I can apply curve_fit to the function. If anyone knows a solution or can see what's wrong with my code, I will be grateful for assistance.

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE: I have used "np.vectorize" on my function and now the error disappeared. Now python is just not doing anything. Even if I run other ipython notebook cells they now do nothing. Anyways, I think this problem is solved.

Comment: `integrand` always needs to return a scalar float, but when you pass a `(500,)` array rather than a float as the first argument to `fsum`, `integrand` will also return a `(500,)` array. Perhaps you want to integrate over values of `x` as well as `chi`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That's actually the problem itself. While most functions will return an array if given an array, the one in my program will not, because of integrand.
I want to input x values and return an integral of chi values.